# Преобразование данных в модели yii2

Tags: yii2, view, model, viewmodel

Здравствуйте.

Есть, к примеру, модель User. В бд существует таблица user и есть поле data (она включает в себя дату и время. запись имеет вид 31.01.2018 13:00:00).

Я создал в модели user поля start_data и start_time.

Как правильно будет сделать метод, который вытащит date и разобьет её на два поля start_date и start_time? Это нужно для того, чтобы можно было редактировать через форму отдельно дату начала, отдельно время начала.

Я представляю, что это будет иметь такой вид в модели.

```
public function createStartDate(){

    $arrDateAndTime = explode(" ",$this->date);

    $start_date = $arrDateAndTime[0];

    return ['start_date' => $start_date];

}

public function createStartTime(){

    $arrDateAndTime = explode(" ",$this->date);

    $full_start_time = explode(':',$arrDateAndTime[1]);

    $start_time = $full_start_time[0] . ":" . $full_start_time[1];

    return ['start_time' => $start_time];

}
```

Как нужно будет вернуть правильно поля, чтобы они отобразились в форме?

В контроллере я просто вызываю нужную модель по id:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $user = User::findOne(540);

    return $this->renderAjax('userchange',['user' => $user]);
}
```

Поля во вью имеет вид:

```
echo $form->field($user, 'start_date');

echo $form->field($user, 'start_time');
```

Comment: $time = date('H:m:i', strtotime($user->data)); $date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($user->data)); // И никакого парсинга строк

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Хм. Можно будет рассмотреть этот вариант. Но уже хочется узнать как будет правильно вернуть поля в модели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментариях Вам предложили лучший вариант формирования даты

Yii сама подгружает нужные данные в поля ActiveForm, если они соответствуют полям модели, некоторые поля мы можем создать искусственно, ниже показал, как это можно сделать

Создаем методы модели User

```
public function afterFind() {
    $date = merge_array($this->createStartDate(), $this->createStartTime());
    $this->date = $date; // после выгрузки из базы делаем из строки массив с помощью Ваших методов
}

public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        $this->date = implode(' ', $this->date); // из массива делаем строку перед загрузкой в базу

        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Далее, инпуты во вью должны иметь другие имена

```
echo $form->field($user, 'date[start_date]');

echo $form->field($user, 'date[start_time]');
```

Еще нужно не забыть проверить и подправить rules

P.S. В этом случае можете закрыть Ваши методы createStartTime и createStartDate - сделайте их приватными.

Comment: Суть понял, спасибо за ответ. Пошел применять.